# Windows Phone sound play

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, audio-streaming

I have a lot of `.wav` files to play and because of that i created `AudioItem` class:

```
public class AudioItem
{
    public string SongName { get; set; }
    public string SongText { get; set; }

    public AudioItem()
    { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize AudioItem class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="SongName">The name of the song(with .wav)</param>
    /// <param name="SongText">Text to display</param>
    public AudioItem(string SongName, string SongText)
    {
        this.SongName = SongName;
        this.SongText = SongText;
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("Sound/" + SongName);
        var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
        effect.Play();
    }

}
```

In the view i have a `Listbox` of items:

```
<ListBox Name="soundtrackLbx">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Name="ListButton" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                            <Button.Content>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Margin="10" Height="30" Width="30" Source="Picture/audio.png"/>
                                    <TextBlock Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding SongText}" FontFamily="Verdana" Tap="TextBlock_Tap" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

my code behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<AudioItem> AudioItems { get; set; }

    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AudioItems = new ObservableCollection<AudioItem>();

        Initialize();
        this.soundtrackLbx.ItemsSource = AudioItems;
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        AudioItems.Add(new AudioItem("ApsolutnoDa.wav", "Apsolutno da"));
        AudioItems.Add(new AudioItem("Da.wav", "Da"));

    }

    private void TextBlock_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock tblock = sender as TextBlock;
        string text = tblock.Text;

        AudioItem item = AudioItems.SingleOrDefault(a => a.SongText == text);
        item.Play();
    }
```

well, it happens that `.wav` sometimes i hear them play, and sometimes i don't, and i have no clue why is that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Here it is, if someone ever got trapped as i did. The problem was because i set the `Tap` event on the `Textblock`, not to the `Button`.

How did i get content from `Button.Content`?

I use `tag` property and i bind it to `SongName` property.